# How to display certain point in QGraphicsScene in the corner of QGraphicsView?

Tags: c++, qt

I need `QGraphicsView` to display part of a scene that is given by its upper-left coordinates, and that scene point must be in the view's corresponding corner.

However i have not found appropriate function to do so out of the box. How can i do that?

Comment: Have you tried QGraphicsView::setSceneRect?

Comment: Setting scene rectangle would work, but it won't allow me to scroll after that. I need to be able to scroll around after sceneview shows interesting part.

Answer (score 3):

By default the view displays scene centered. This can prevent it from fine positioning, so you should change view's alignment:

```
view->setAlignMent(Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop);
```

When you want some `point` (in the scene coordinates) to be shown, you need to convert it to viewport coordinates:

```
QPoint viewport_point = view->mapFromScene(point);
```

Now you need to set appropriate value of scrollbars:

```
view->horizontalScrollBar()->setValue(viewport_point.x());
view->verticalScrollBar()->setValue(viewport_point.y());
```

That should do it. Note that scrolling in the view has limitations. For example, you can't put the scene's right edge to the viewport's left edge. You can make view's `sceneRect` larger to overcome that.

`QGraphicsView::ensureVisible` method also may be helpful although it doesn't do exactly what you ask.